# Realm. Разница между createObject и copyToRealm

Tags: android, база-данных, realm, realm-database

Изучаю `Realm`, читаю документацию. Написано,

> To add your Dog object to a Realm, use the createObject or copyToRealm
>   methods

Разницы между этими двумя методами не написано, хотелось бы узнать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто. Вы либо создаете новый **Realm** объект внутри транзакции, либо копируете уже созданный где-то еще объект.

Основная разница в том, что объект созданный через `createObject` сразу становится управляемым. Объект же созданный обычным способом, станет управляемым, только когда вы его получите из базы.